# Encrypt database entries in my android app

Tags: java, android, encryption, aes, pbkdf2

I am developing a android app. I created a share function, which uploads data from a local SQLite database to a online MySQL database.

Now my question is: How is it possible to encrypt the database entries? **One important point for me is, to have a master key for trouleshooting.**

How can I implement that? Are there libraries which do that already? I haven't found a good solution yet.

Thanks!

Comment: `Are there libraries which do that already` you should not ask for a library here. You can manually encrypt and decrypt each cell of data.

Comment: Did you see CryptDB. There are attacks on it but you might consider similar about ideas.

Comment: I don't want to encrypt the local DB. I want to encrypt the online DB. But keep in mind: I want to have a master key. How is it possible to implement that?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [link](http://greenrobot.org/greendao/documentation/database-encryption/) 
Android doesn't provides any encryption out of the box for databases. You can either go with native code or try using the library GreenDAO, which uses SQLCipher and it builds database on 256-bit AES encryption.
Note: This encrypts your database not the entries inside it.